# Что такое вектор и для чего он?

Tags: c++, vector

объясните пожалуйста, что такое вектор в C++ и для чего он нужен?

Comment: каждый раз, когда в с++ хочется иметь возможность добавить в массив элементы, Вам нужен вектор вместо обычного массива.

Comment: Чтобы ответ был полезен для вас, нужно понять какого именно рода ответ вы хотите услышать. Например, чем вас не устраивают описания на википедии и https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Кратко говоря, вектор - аналог динамичным массивам